# Preventing a page break after a todonote

Tags: page-breaking, todonotes

I use the `todo` command from the `todonotes` package to insert margin notes. I use them to keep track of the status of single chapters.

LaTeX often puts a page break after the todo note, which looks strange and is confusing. How can I prevent that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}
    \blindtext[2]
    
    xxx
    
    xxx
    
    xxx
    
    \blindtext
    
    \section{My Section}
    \todo[noline]{needs rework}
    
    \blindtext
    
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Since `\todo` and what I normally use `\fxnote` from `fixme` (as, with the right configuration, `fixme` can be used in more places as `\todo`), places a `whatsit` when used, this can cause interesting outputs when uses right after a `\section`, note how the `Lorem ipsum` on page 2 starts indented whereas it does not in section 1. I normally just live with it, or add the note after the first word of the paragraph.